# Held broken packages in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, package-management

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04 but my upgrade paused on `libc6-dev` for around 2 hours.  I rebooted my system and now I'm getting you have held broken packages.  I've tried looking through other posts but none of the fixes seem to work for me and I just don't think I know enough to fix it myself.

In synaptic package manager I'm getting

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I'm unsure what to do in terminal to try and fix this.  I seem to be working fine in 10.04 still but without fixing this I can't upgrade to 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Go into synaptic package manager,
 Edit > Fix broken Packages.
Apply.

Comment: Unfortunately, In some cases, "Fix broken packages" results in error messages instead of repairing the system.